# Configure Grails controller to download file in browser after retrieving data from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, grails, download

My controller in Grails first fetches the data from a remote service API, and the returned data is a String. Then I would like to have the data downloaded as a csv file in the browser. I came across a similar post on SO and stole the code for using the response as below:

```
String exportResults = dataService.getDataFromService()
response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=data_export.csv"
response.contentType = 'text/csv'
response.outputStream << exportResults.getBytes() //getBytes() not portable
response.outputStream.flush()
```

But **this does not trigger any download window in the browser**. I was wondering why. I use AngularJS to make a POST request to the controller and resolve the promise as below (JavaScript code):

```
ExportService.exportData(some_params).then(function(data) {
               $log.info('export promise resolved: ');
               //window.open(data, '_blank', ''); //not working
               }).catch(function(err) {
               $scope.message = "failed to retrieve data from export service";
               $log.error(err);
               }).finally(function(complete) {
                 $scope.message = "Data export completed.";
               });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `'text/csv'` with `'application/octet-stream'` for `response.contentType`. The content type `'application/octet-stream'` is used for a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after `response.outputStream.flush()` and see if it works.

```
webRequest.renderView = false
```

You can even try looking [here](http://lalitagarw.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-forcing-file-download.html).